# Making all Facebook posts visible to only me

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Is there any way to make all Facebook posts visible to only me (without having to manually change the visibility of each post one by one)?

Comment: @pnuts simply wall cleaning :) (but I would like to keep the posts to myself as a log)

Answer (score 1):

Currently Facebook allow the option to change the control of the future post alone to make it visible .If you need you can change it from following settings  Click on downward arrow on top right corner  and then  settings -> privacy.Then who can see the stuff and change it to me for the future post.